# How do I find a HTML div contains specific text after a text prefix?

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have following string:

`<div> text0 </div> prefix <div> text1 <strong>text2</strong> text3 </div> text4`

and want to know wether it contains `text3` inside divs that go after prefix:

`prefix<div>...text3...</div>`

but I don't know how ta make regex for that, since I can't use `[^<]+` because div's can contain `strong` tag inside.

Please help

EDIT:

1. Div tags after prefix are guaranted to be not nested
2. Language is C#
3. Text4 is very long, so regex must not look after closing div

EDIT2: I don't want to use html parser, it can be easily (and MUCH faster) achieved with Regex. HTML there is simple: no attributes in tags; no nesting div's. And even some % of wrong answers are acceptable in my case.

Comment: You can't (reliably) use regex for this, because as you've noted Regular Expressions don't deal with non-Regular language features, such as HTML's nesting/etc. **You need to use a HTML DOM parser - what language are you trying to do this?**

Comment: You probably want to get to know jquery

Comment: What language? Different languages support different RegEx features and they are _not_ identical. Even if RegEx is the wrong solution, recommendations of a good solution require knowledge of what language you are using.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: That should be an automatic answer, if someone asks this question  :)

Comment: Poma, for C# take a look at HtmlAgilityPack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: leppie - yep, and there's a couple of discussions on Meta about how to do that. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/a-question-wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my new regex:

`prefix<div>([^<]*<(?!/div>))*[^<]*text3([^<]*<(?!/div>))*[^<]*</div>`

seems to work ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn off the "greedy" option, you should be able to just use something like `prefix<div>.*text3.*</div>`. (If the `<div>` is allowed to have attributes, use `prefix<div[^>]*>.*text3.*</div>` instead.)

Numerous improvements could be made to this in order to take account of unusual spacing, `>`s within quotes, `</div>` within quotes, etc.

Patterns like `prefix<div>...<div></div>text3</div>` would be more difficult. You might have to capture all of the occurrences of the `div` tag so that you could count how many `div` tags were open at a given time.

EDIT: Oops, turning off the greedy option won't always give the right result, even in examples other than the one above. Probably better just to capture all occurrences of the `div` tag and go from there. As noted above by Peter, HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and so you can't use regular expressions to do everything you might want with it.

Answer (score 0):

For **C# + HtmlAgilityPack** you can do something like:

```
InputString = Regex.Replace(InputString,"^(?:[^<]+?|<[^>]*>)*?prefix","");

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(InputString);

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains('text3')]");
```

The prefix removal is still not a good way of dealing with it. Ideally you'd do something like using HtmlAgilityPack to find where `prefix` occurs in the DOM, translate that to provide the position in the string, then do a substring(pos,len) (or equivalent) to look at only the relevant text (you can also avoid looking at text4 using similar method).
I'm afraid I can't translate all that into code right now; hopefully someone else can help there.

---

*(original answer, before extra details provided)*
Here is a **JavaScript + jQuery** solution:

```
var InputString = '<div>text0 </div> prefix <div>text1 <strong>text2</strong> text3 </div> text4';

InputString = InputString.replace(/^.*?prefix/,'');

var MatchingDivs = jQuery('div:contains(text3)','<div>'+InputString+'</div>')

console.log(MatchingDivs.get());
```

This makes use of jQuery's ability to accept a [context as second argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) (though it appears this needs to be wrapped in `div` tags to actually work).

Comment: Splitting by `prefix` and then trying to parse one of the resulting substrings could also result in parse errors if prefix occurs within a tag. (I haven't used jQuery, though, so I don't know how it would behave in such a situation.)

Comment: Yeah, that bit is certainly not great, but my brain isn't awake enough to come up with a proper solution for it. :( I have improved it slightly by switching to a replace though.